# Kendo MVC line chart tooltip from model

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, linechart

In a Kendo MVC line chart, when the user hovers over a point, I'd like to display several custom values, resulting in a tooltip looking something like:

```
Date produced: 10/18/2018
Quality value: A+
Grade: STD
```

Obviously, each point would display different values. I've seen other posts that refer to template dataitem, but can't figure out how to populate the dataitem. Can someone steer me in the right direction?

Thx,
Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I was using an unbound chart. Once I bound my chart to a list of classes, I was able to reference a class property as my dataItem, such as .Template("#=dataItem.DateProduced#")